# IP address accessing protected folder

Tags: asp.net, windows, security, ip

Is it possible for an unallowed IP address to access the protected area using "Ipv4 address and domain restriction" ?

I have a protected subdomain on my server where I allow only a few IP addresses to access it and alert me through email after every successful visit, but I got an email just now alerting me that unlisted IP address have visited the protected folder.is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you get ip address of client. For example if one of client come from behind the proxy or load balancer, client's requets will contain X-FORWARDED-FOR in http header. If your asp.net codes gets this information instead of real ip address that can lead to bypass ip protection. In order to be sure that is impact for your application you must be sure about the way of grabbing ip address of user.

You will see the details of what I was trying the explain. [How to pass HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR to aspx pages from IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478836/how-to-pass-http-x-forwarded-for-to-aspx-pages-from-iis)

In conclusion, sometimes frameworks or method can return X-FORWARDED-FOR or similar header variables instead of real ip address. You need to be sure about these mechanism.